# Showing that $\gamma$ is a homeomorphism betrween $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ and $D^2$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, normed-spaces

Observe $\gamma : [-1,1]\times [-1,1]\to D^2$ given by$$\gamma  :  \begin{cases}0, \quad \quad \quad \, \,\,(x,y)= (0,0) \\ \frac{||(x,y)||_{2}}{||(x,y)||_\infty}\cdot (x,y), \quad (x,y)\neq(0,0)\end{cases}$$
This function maps for each $0 < d \leq 1$, the border of each square $\{ (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \text{max}( \lvert x_1 \rvert, \lvert x_2 \rvert) \leq d \}$ into the circle of radius d centered at the origin.

Since we can write down the inverse explictly:$$\gamma^{-1} :  \begin{cases}0, \quad \quad \quad \, \,\,(x,y)= (0,0) \\ \frac{||(x,y)||_\infty}{||(x,y)||_{2}}\cdot (x,y), \quad (x,y)\neq (0,0)\end{cases}$$ we can conclude that $\gamma$ is bijective.

I am having trouble showing that $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{-1}$ are continuous however. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your current function takes on values that are non-negative real numbers; are you sure this is the function you want?

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear; your $\gamma$ is a map from $[-1,1]^2$ to $[0,1]$; The same is true for your $\gamma^{-1}$ (which also means it isn't an inverse function). I don't think this is what you want --- you won't be able to find a homeomorphism between $[-1,1]^2$ and $[0,1]$.

Comment: $D^2=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x||_2 \leq 1\}$.

Comment: I understand; I meant more that the $\gamma$ you suggested does not map onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ at all; the $p$-norms employed in the definition take on real values, as does does their ratio (and thus, $\gamma$, too.) For example, $\gamma(1)=1$, which is not in $D^2$.

Comment: You have to multiply the scalars (quotients of norms) by the vector $(x,y$ to get a “ radial” homeomorphism. It’s pretty clear that multiplication by a continuously varying scalar gives a continuous map. And norms as functions are continuous hence so are their quotients.

Comment: Henno Brandsma corrected the question. I'm sorry for causing confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the two norms $\lVert - \rVert_2$ and $\lVert - \rVert_\infty$. The "unit disk" with respect to the first norm is $D^2$ and with respect to the second norm is $[-1,1]^2$. All norms on $\mathbb R^2$ (or more generally  $\mathbb R^n$) are equivalent and are thus continuous real-valued functions with respect to the standard Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R^n$. For the above two norms you can prove this also completely elementary without invoking the general norm-equivalence theorem.

Therefore $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{-1}$ are continuous in all $\xi \ne 0$. But they are also continuous in $0$ since
$$\lVert \gamma(\xi) - \gamma(0) \rVert_\infty = \lVert \gamma(\xi) \rVert_\infty = \lVert x \rVert_2 = \lVert x -  0 \rVert_2 ,$$
$$\lVert \gamma^{-1}(\xi) - \gamma^{-1}(0) \rVert_2 =  \lVert x -  0 \rVert_\infty .$$